# Error creating IpcChannel on German XP machine in .NET Remoting

Tags: c#, remoting, .net-remoting

When I make this call:

```
RemotingConfiguration.Configure(QviDBXml.NetworkConfigName, false);
```

I get the following exception result.

> UcpService: .NET Remoting startup exception: Message: Remoting configuration failed with the exception 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Security.Principal.IdentityNotMappedException: Some or all identity references could not be translated.
>      at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Ipc.IpcServerChannel.StartListening(Object data)

The exe.config file is in the proper folder and this works great on the same machine when it is configured to run in USA-English.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Since the exception is an `IdentityNotMappedException`, I would assume this is auth related.  You should let us know how this is set up for your service.

Comment: Since the exception details mentions not being able to translate the identity, would that mean that the OS is trying to translate the username? The current logged in user is the default Administrator account. I don't have access to the server's config file right now, but I will post that tomorrow if that would help understand this.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the problem was that my .config file had incorrect authorization data in it:

```
<channel ref="ipc" portName="qviucp" authorizedGroup="Everyone" exclusiveAddressUse="false">       
    <serverProviders> 
        <formatter ref="binary" typeFilterLevel="Full" /> 
    </serverProviders> 
</channel>
```

Once I set the authorizedGroup="Jeder", the service started fine.